# How to safely override save method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a RoR app (in development). I have models based on sql views.

However, I would like to create & update thoses models. They are stored in database through 2 tables (generic design pattern, that's why I use sql views).

I've heard about hooks such as before_save, but as mentioned [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_save) there is still issues saving or updating other objects in `before_save` callback.

So, I am wonderring how to safely override save method in rails ?

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks

EDIT :

sql of my view

```
CREATE VIEW my_objects AS
SELECT o.* ,
at.value as "column1",
FROM
Generic_object o 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT at.* FROM Another_table at ON at.genreic_object_id = o.id AND at.name = "param1" )
```

This lead to a "reconstructed" object from my generic table and some column from another table :

> o.col1, o.col2, ..., at.param1

If my object have several parameters I have to JOIN the another table again, like this

> LEFT JOIN ( SELECT at2.* FROM Another_table at2 ON at2.generic_object_id = o.id AND at2.name = "param2")

And then, i get this object :

> o.col1, o.col2, ..., at.param1, at2.param2

It seems rare (weird? :p), but this pattern is my constraint.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save
# new object ?
  # yes
  q = Array.new
  qualifiers.each  do |qk|
    q.push(Another_table.create(value: self.read_attribute(qk),name: qk))
  end
  e = Generic_object.create(name: name,type: self.class,qualifiers: q)

  # existing object 
  #bla bla
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I rarely find such need to I override common methods. And I don't recommend so because there will be other code depends on the original method. Your problem must have another better solution.

However, if you really have to, you can safely override it by Ruby's `alias_method`, or `alias_method_chain` provided by ActivitySupport.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_method_chain :save, :my_feature

  def save
    blah_blah
    save_without_my_feature # The original save method
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried this solution.
And when save (without features) is triggered, it raises an exception (I'm working with sql view basde model).
May I store another objects to save method of a sql view based model ?